# can't add getted elements from sql query to array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
function get_comment_count_for_events() {
    $query = "SELECT event_token , COUNT(NULLIF(event_token, '')) AS counts FROM comment GROUP BY event_token ORDER BY counts DESC;";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $comment_count = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $comment_count = $row;
    }
    if (!$result) {
        trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . " in " . $query);
    }
    return $comment_count;
}
```

---

This is my function.

I use it from other file

```
foreach (get_comment_count_for_events() as $comment_count_event) {
    echo $comment_count_event['tiken_event'];
    echo $comment_count_event['count'];
}
```

But in databese when i test query it's work:
result:
event_token - counts

1 - 13

2 - 13

8 - 11

3 - 8

5 - 7

7 - 4

6 - 3

''- 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code, you are overriding your `$comment_count` variable. You need to use array instead;

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $comment_count[] = $row;
}
```

Also in your second iteration ,field names are incorrect. Update them also;

```
foreach (get_comment_count_for_events() as $comment_count_event) {
    echo $comment_count_event['event_token'];
    echo $comment_count_event['counts'];
}
```

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array(-----my mistake----$result------)) {